# JS: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_image");
for( i=0; i < a.length ; i++){
  var b = a[i];
  b.style.width = "100px";
  b.style.height = "100px";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_image").alt;
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_image");

if (x = "Cool Beans") {
  y.style.width = "200px";
  y.style.height = "200px";
}
</script>
```

The first script, changes the image size of all images which works but it makes some other images look "ugly".

The second script is where I get the `Cannot: set property 'width' of undefined.` error. I'm telling JS to look for the first alt tag that contains "Cool Beans" and if found change the style width and height. What is wrong? I believe it has to do something with my declaration of `var y` but I don't have a clue to fix it.

Comment: Check that x and y aren't undefined?

Comment: if (x = "Cool Beans") should be if (x === "Cool Beans")

Comment: [Always check the documentation of how to use a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), getElementsBy* functions always returns a NodeList (like an array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array (you can tell this by the plural name: getElement**s**By*Something*).

So, you must set index of `x` and `y` to operate on one element of the array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_image");    

for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].alt === "Cool Beans") {
     x[i].style.width = "200px";
     x[i].style.height = "200px";
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work the way you expect.

You must iterate your elements and find the right one.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("sub_category_image");
for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var b = a[i];
    if (b.alt == "Cool Beans") {
        b.style.width = "100px";
        b.style.height = "100px";
    }
}
```